# Struggling with Limits Question

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

> Let $$f \left( x \right) := 1 + e^{\ln \left(\ln \left(x\right)\right)} \cdot \ln \left(k^2+25\right), \qquad \qquad g \left( x \right) := \frac{1}{\left|x\right|-1}$$ If $$\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \left( f \left( x \right) \right)^{g\left(x\right)} = k\left(2\sin ^2\left(\alpha\right)+3\cos \left(\beta\right)+5\right)$$ where $k>0$ and $\alpha, \beta \in \Bbb R$, then which of the following is (are) correct? 
>  (A) The value of k is equal to 5. 
>  (B) The value of $\frac{\left(\sin ^5\left(α\right)+\cos ^5\left(β\right)\right)}{\sin ^2\left(α\right)+\cos \left(β\right)}$ is equal to 1. 
>  (C) $\cos ^2\left(β\right)+\sin ^4\left(α\right)=2$ 
>  (D) $\cos \left(β\right)<\sin ^2\left(α\right)$

---

I tried solving by transforming $\lim _{x\to 1}\left(f\left(x\right)\right)^{g\left(x\right)}$ to the power of 'e' but that I am stuck after that. How should I proceed further?

Comment: The quantity $\lim_{x \to 1} (f(x))^{g(x)}$ is equal to $k^2 + 25$ but the calculations are so painstakingly trivial and monotonous that I doubt there is any value in adding them in (plus the process of Latexing them). Where is this question from if you do not mind my asking?

Comment: Not really sure about the source, most probably my teacher framed the question. Oh, no need to latex it, that's fine. If possible please send a pic or at least give me some hints. I am still new to these concepts so any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please use `\alpha` and `\beta` instead.

Comment: The first thing to note is that $f(x) = 1 + C\ln x$, where the constant $C = \ln(k^2 + 25)$. Next is that $f(x)^{g(x)} = \exp(g(x) \ln f(x))$. Then you can apply L'Hopital's rule to $$\lim_{x \to 1}g(x)\ln f(x) = \lim_{x\to 1}\dfrac{\ln(1+C\ln x)}{|x| - 1}$$

Comment: Another thing you should note is that $0 \le \sin^2 \alpha \le 1$ and $-1 \le \cos \beta \le 1$.

Comment: Hi, Paul. I still can't get to the answer. After applying LH Rule I find myself stuck again over here. I have been able to simplify the limit till here $e^{\frac{\left(\log \:_e\left(k^2+25\right)\right)}{x\left(1+\log _e\left(k^2+25\right)\right)}}$